# Removing city from the api react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function DataWeather({ weather, setWeather }) {
  const cityName = weather.city.name;
  const countryName = weather.city.country;
  const minTemp = weather.list.main.temp_min;
  const maxTemp = weather.list.main.temp_max;

  const handleRemoveItem = (id) => {
    setWeather((weather) => weather.filter((city) => city.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span onClick={handleRemoveItem}>
          x
        </span>
        <p>
          {cityName} {countryName}
        </p>
        <p>MaxTemp : {maxTemp}</p>
        <p>MinTemp: {minTemp}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataWeather;
```

Hey, I'm trying to remove city from coming api, but i get error that filter is not a function. Anyone has idea why I get this error. I have initialize weather with useState([]).

```
function WeatherData() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const FetchData = async (e) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${query},&appid=${YOU_API}`
      );
      const weatherData = await response.json();
      setWeather(weatherData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <form onSubmit={FetchData}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Click"
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            value={query}
          />

          {Object.entries(weather).length !== 0 ? (
            <DataProfile weather={weather} setWeather={setWeather} />
          ) : (
            <h3> Please City Name </h3>
          )}
          <button className="btn">Click</button>
        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

as you can see here is the rest of my code fetching the weather api to get the detail of this api. I just want to remove the data by clicking the X.

Comment: Is `weather` an array?

Comment: `filter is not a function` that shows you should add a checker that weather is an array or not.+

Comment: Provide a minimum reproducible example, weather is not an array for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `weather` is an object so you can't delete it with `filter`.

You can use spread operator to update object like this:

```
  const handleRemoveItem = (id) => {
    setWeather((weather) => ({...weather, city: {}}));
  };
```

Comment: it's just remove city. How i remove all the object

Comment: Do you want to remove all field in `weather`?

Comment: Yes. all field weather.

Comment: If you remove all fields, `weather.city` and `weather.list` becomes undefined. So `weather.city.name;` and other will error

Comment: how could i remove all the data from this filed and list is array of objetc.

Comment: Please show your detail array and detail code

Comment: as you can see the whole code. i'm want to remove the whole data when i clicking the span. its better to use filter, but i get an error that filter is not a function.